# HTML & CSS Floats help (very basic)

Tags: css-float

I've been doing the codeacademy HTML/CSS course and understood it fine right up until the end where I had to 'Build a Resume'. I've compared my code to the example at the start of the exercise but I just can't understand why my .right class is sitting at the far right and not lining up correctly. Also the header and the footer are the same width (95%) but the footer is noticeably smaller and doesn't stretch as far across the screen as the header.

Any idea's?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>

div {
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#header {
    width: 95%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
}

.left {
    position: relative;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    height: 400px;
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 60px;
}

.right {
    position: relative;
    background-color: lightgray;
    height: 400px;
    width: 74%;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#footer {
    position: relative;
    background-color: gray;
    width: 95%;
    height: 60px;
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your `.right` is sitting at the far right because of `float: right;`, telling the div to float to the right until it hits something(screen/browser edge or another div). If you want it to connect snugly against your left div, try `float: left;`, which will float that div towards and against your existing `.left` div.

Comment: I tried that and it works great, I just needed to add a little margin-left on the .right so it lines up nicely.

Thanks

Comment: as far as the header & footer go when I tried setting the same width on both it worked fine for me. Only thing I noticed is a possible optical illusion of different size because the header was overlapping the content bit while the footer stays clear of everything.